# MySQL 3 table cross/left join optimization

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables
Table1 has id cell
Table2 has id cell
Table3 has id1 cell -> corresponds to Table1.id
Table3 has id2 cell -> corresponds to Table2.id
Table3 has a timestamp, for looking only last day of data

Table1 and Table2 has more more data which just needs to be returned.

```
SELECT
    t1.name AS t1name,
    t1.id AS t1id,
    t2.name AS t2name,
    t2.id AS t2id,
    t2.surname AS t2surname,
    t2.served AS t2served,
    t2.reported AS t2reported,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t3.id1 IS NOT NULL AND t3.id2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS t3hits
FROM t1
CROSS JOIN t2
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.id = t3.id1 AND t2.id = t3.id2 AND t3.time > SUBDATE(NOW(),1)
GROUP BY t1.id, t2.id
ORDER BY t3hits,t2served,t2reported ASC LIMIT 10
```

This takes 12.45s with my current tables.

```
t1 is small, 20 records or so
t2 is 100k records or so
t3 is 100k records and growing
```

Using PHP for serving via http...

Ive put indexes all over the place, but its still slow :)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Here is Explain and indexes

[image]

and as text:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra

1   SIMPLE  t1  index   NULL    id1unique   50  NULL    13  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort

1   SIMPLE  t2  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    11652   Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)

1   SIMPLE  t3  ref ids_index   ids_index   8   id1,id2 1   Using where

Indexes 
id1unique   t1.id                               
ids_index   id1,id2
```

**More explanation of why is it used**

```
t1 is a set of customers

t2 is a set of products

t3 has id of a customer and product and timestamp when it was purchased
```

I want to serve the customer products they have not purchased in last 24h , or products that were purchased the least in the last 24h
Thats the whole process :)

Comment: Please edit the question to add details about Indexing on the table(s); Result of `Explain` statement would also be desirable

Comment: You know that a CROSS JOIN generates all possibilities between table t1 and t2 rights so it's making `20 *  100.000 = 2000000` records right?.. So iam wondering do you really need to use a CROSS JOIN here?  like @MadhurBhaiya said make example data and expected output iam pretty sure there is is more optimal way..

Comment: I know its complex, but is there any other way of getting the count of occurrences of pair of ids?

Comment: One optimization you can do is limiting the left join table before joining to it, example: `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM t3 WHERE t3.time > SUBDATE(NOW(),1) ) AS t4 ON t1.id = t4.id1 AND t2.id = t4.id2`. Note that an **index** on **t3.time** will help the performing of this also.

Comment: "I know its complex" it's not really complex.. it's indeed complex to make a query/answer without knowing table structures, example data and expected output as formatted text.. those give alot more information then some explainment text and query and explain output from which we must reverse engineer.. i advice you to read "Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: "I want to serve the customer products they have not purchased in last 24h , or products that were purchased the least in the last 24h " Besides your current qeury does not looks like it implements both cases at first look..

Comment: With 100,000 products I think we can assume that most products will not have been bought by a particular customer within the last 24 hours. So with 20 customers, you may have, say, 20,000 distinct product/customer pairs in t3 within the last 24 hours. So 2,980,000 pairs that don't exist in t3 for this time range. The number of t3 rows you count is zero for these pairs. And of these 2,980,000 you pick 10 with `LIMIT 10`. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: It is not normal customer, product relation. They buy most products everyday, some few times...

Comment: @D. Smania this helped, but like 50%
from 15s to 10s, thought still would need better solution.
Thanks

Comment: @Milika, you are sure you need to get all the combinations between customers (**t1**) and products (**t2**) and show a **0 counter** when there exists no reports on table **t3** in the latests 24hs? If you don't need these 0 counter reports you can start first restricting table **t3** and then inner join with **t1** and **t2** for get customers and products names.

Comment: @D. Smaina Im afraid that exactly those 0 results are the most valuable, only if customer purchased everything, then we need to serve him with the lease purchased items.
Perhaps 2 queries, one if customer did not purchase anything, and second only if needed?

Comment: Your description is misleading and you should edit it. You said that t3 has about 100,000 rows. Now you say that we can expect almost each customer to buy almost each product every day. That means with 20 customers and 100k products the table grows by about 2 million rows per day, maybe more, and when you said that t3 contains 100k rows, that was only because you had started the whole process only some 12 minutes before.

Answer (score 0):

I'd aggregate before joining. After all you want to know the number of t3 rows per id1/id2, so join the "number of rows":

```
SELECT
  t1.name AS t1name,
  t1.id AS t1id,
  t2.name AS t2name,
  t2.id AS t2id,
  t2.surname AS t2surname,
  t2.served AS t2served,
  t2.reported AS t2reported,
  COALESCE(t3agg.cnt, 0) AS t3hits
FROM t1
CROSS JOIN t2
LEFT JOIN 
(
  select id1, id2, count(*) as cnt
  from t3
  where t3.time > subdate(now(), 1)
  group by id1, id2
) t3agg ON t1.id = t3agg.id1 AND t2.id = t3agg.id2
ORDER BY t3hits, t2served, t2reported
LIMIT 10;
```

You should have this index:

```
create index idx3 on t3(time, id1, id2);
```

The index enables the DBMS to find the relatively few rows for the last 24 hours quickly and use the id1 and id2 immediately without looking up the rows in the table.

You can even make this

```
create index idx3 on t3(time, id1, id2, name);
```

so the table doesn't even have to be read for the name. That should be about as fast as it gets.

Comment: Results seem ok, but query took 91.06s, those indexes were already added

Comment: So my query was eight times as slow as yours. But according to your request comments, t3 grows by some 2 million rows per day. As you ran my query six hours after your request, I suppose that t3 contained about 600,000 rows then, which is six times as much as when you ran your own query. Is this so?

Comment: If you ran my query with 100k t3 rows only, then it is strange that my query is slower than yours. After all the DBMS shall retrieve the same data. Ideally MySQL would generate the same execution plan for both queries. If it generates a much worse plan for my query its optimizer does a bad job. Does "those indexes were already added" mean you added them before running my query ot that you already had them when you ran yours?

Comment: Much before, also, data set stays the same, because its looking only last day of data... So there shoudnt be any problems...

Comment: So t3 only contains the last 24 hours? Why then `AND t3.time > SUBDATE(NOW(),1)`? And why only 100k rows, when you say that almost all 20 customers order almost all 100,000 products daily. That makes 2 million records not 100k.

Comment: Your right, at full speed that would be the situation